# Categorizations for Ruby on Rails (or tags)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

I have Articles, Profiles, and Comments. What would be the best way to categorize new instances of each of these? When a user creates a new article, profile, or comment, he must select a category for them. I want to have a drop down menu from which he can select the categories. The categories are different for each Model, and what categories appear in one model cannot appear in another.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way that users will be able to add new categories for any of those models?

Comment: Yes, except, I would limit it to just admins. I was thinking to create new categories, I would just set it up so the admin has access to the categories resources (create, new, etc) so they could modify the categories and which model they belong to. Then, the user could post an article and specify from one of the categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for categories or 'tags', I recommend this gem,

http://github.com/TylerRick/acts_as_taggable .

Seems to be a reasonable fit for you.

For the drop down menu, I would follow this blog here:

http://www.softiesonrails.com/2008/4/10/absolute-moron-s-guide-to-forms-in-rails-part-5

That's what got me started in making complex drop downs made out of dynamic models. That section, Part 5 speaks specifically about what you're asking, but you may have to backtrack to part 1 ( I recommend it ), to see how he built up to it.

Good luck!